# how to rewrite search[] to something else with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have created a search form with get method. But when the url looks like this **search.php?search[]** or **search?search[]** (mod_rewrite) then I get a sql fattal error. It's passing an array and I want to avoid that problem.

my question is how do I redirect a person from that url to search.php

Comment: You should be sanitizing this before it hits your database anyway.

Comment: yes I do this with mysqli_real_escape_string() function, but it prints out the error for that line. that's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are directly passing the `?search[]` query string variable into your SQL.  mod_rewrite won't fix this for you... what if I decide to call your page with `http://www.yoursite.com/search.php?search=;DROP TABLE users;`?  You simply aren't able to use mod_rewrite to predict all the bad kinds of input that a user can come up with.

Your code needs to be doing input validation and sanitization.  **You must assume that everything your script receives from the user is malicious and dangerous.**  That includes all data inside `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

The right solution here is to check that `$_GET['search']` is a valid value to be passing to your SQL.  Something like:

```
if (is_string($_GET['search']) && ! empty($_GET['search']) {
    //escape the input properly using your database-specific method, e.g.:
    $searchParam = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
    //run your query with the escaped data
}
```

At a minimum, that would ensure that your passed in search variable was not an empty string.

Comment: I was allready using mysqli_real_escape_string(); so that's a good thing but I was using isset() to see it if existed, going to try out is_string();

Comment: perfect, worked but I had to use isset() first otherwise I had "undefined index: ..."